# connect to mongodb remotely node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodejitsu

I know this is kind of trivial, but I have been searching on google for a solution to this problem, this here is my first time deploying a mongodb+node.js application, I have succeeded in hosting a node.js application with static data, I have changed it to use a database -mongodb, I have created a mongodb database on mongolab.com,
I have tried connecting but I keep getting this error

Database error

Error details: Error: failed to connect to [subdomain.mongolab.com:10027]

I have been searching over google, did not get a solution, have also contacted the site admin, my database connection and the entire code to fetch from mongodb remotely is
[here](https://github.com/ysfkel/node)  on  github , thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect using mongo shell. mongo --host <hostname> --port <port-addr> -u<username> -p<password> <dbname> ?
Paste the error if it comes.

Comment: Its okay now, it appears the database name I specified was not used, but the system generated a different database name other than what I specified, still learning

Comment: what's your subdomain on mongolab? i think it's usually analogous to the database name.